# Windowbuilder does not start. Always ClassCastException

Tags: eclipse, swt, windowbuilder

Using a fresh Eclipse Indigo install (updated), creating a fresh (SWT/JFace- support) project, creating a New SWT ApplicationWindow all seems OK. The new file is available in the editor, and compiles - run produces a new, empty window, as it should.

(The above is to say I have no manually-created code in the workspace.  It's all-new, all-fresh, all-wizard created).

Pressing the "Design" tab cause a modal progress dialogue to appear, with the message "Parsing...", which hangs at about 15% in. The editor windows underneath the progress message are replaced with a general message about a WindowsBuilder internal error - the last line of which is always

ClassCastException cannot cast org.eclipse.swt.shell.Shell to org.eclipse.swt.widget.Widget

I searched real hard - Google doesn't show anyone with a similar problem.

Screenshot of error https://i.stack.imgur.com/WA170.png

(Note: If it's a Swing-based GUI, WindowBuilder starts and seems fine)

Can you help me get Windowbuilder to start-up with a SWT GUI?

(Note: Repost, as previously, it was off-topic in the original post)

Comment: When installing WindowBuilder you can select for which UI toolkit you want support. Did you selected the right one?

Comment: I used the Eclipse in-built "Install New Software" and "Check for updates".  So I assume it's the correct one, at the correct version.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried using Window Builder Pro with several versions of Eclipse - 3.6, 3.7 and 4.2 (with the respective version of Window Builder Pro of course). The problem with the SWT Design tab occurs with each version. When I check the installed software in Eclipse, it is clearly visible that the correct UI toolkit has been installed in order for Window Builder Pro to support SWT.
Similar to Fred Trellis, Window Builder Pro works fine with Swing.

Comment: I fixed the problem by updating my JDK.
The one I had was JDK SE7 update 13, which I updated to JDK SE7 update 17.